# Keeping Selected Item selected in a combo box

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, combobox, selecteditem

In a Visual Basic program for school I have a combo box of drop down style simple. When a user enters text into the text field of the combo box and also a separate text box and presses the Add button, the program adds the text in the combo box text field to the items in the combo box and adds the value in the text box to a corresponding array. That's all working peachy.

The problem is that there has to be a change button. The instructions for this are as follows:

> The user may update an item in the combo box by selecting it, retyping
>   it in the text box portion of the combo box and/or retyping the number
>   in the textbox and clicking the Change button.

My current code is not working at all. The problem is that whenever I select an item in the combo box and then click the text box portion of it or the other text box, editing the text causes the combobox to deselect. I need it to stay selected so that I can change the item to the new value(s). Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

it's really easy, you just have to do this on your button.click event.

```
 ComboBox1.Items(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex) = textbox1.text
```

Comment: The problem is that he wants it to come out of the combobox's text field rather than a separate textbox. The information in the textbox changes information in an array of doubles.